# Using python/numpy to create a complex matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

Using python/numpy, I would like to create a 2D matrix M whose components are:

[image]

I know I can do this with a bunch of for loops but is there a better way to do this by using numpy (not using for loops)?

---

This is how I tried, which end up giving me a value error.

I tried to first define a function that takes the sum over k:

```
define sum_function(i,j):
    initial_array = np.arange(g(i,j),h(i,j)+1)
    applied_array = f(i,j,initial_array)
    return applied_array.sum()
```

then I tried to create the M matrix with np.mgrid as follows:

```
ii, jj = np.mgrid(start:fin, start:fin)
M_matrix = sum_function(ii,jj)
```

--

(Edited)
Let me write down the concrete form of a matrix as an example:
M_{i,j} = \sum_{k=min(i,j)}^{i+j}\sin{\left( (i+j)^k \right)}

[image]

if i,j = 0,1, then this matrix is 2 by 2 and it's form will be 
\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\sin(0) & \sin(1) \ 
 \sin(1)& \sin(2)+\sin(4) 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)

[image]

Now if the matrix gets really big, how would I create this matrix without using for loops?

Comment: You must be more explicit, what is `k` argument in the function `f`?

Comment: Look at `ii,jj`.  Those are arrays, with all index values.  Your `sum_function` only works with scalar `i,j` inputs.  For example the arguments to `arange` have to scalars, not arrays or lists.

Comment: Just to clarify: `g(i,j)` is that a function `g` that takes scalar inputs?  Or array `g` with `i,j` indices?  You may need to give a full working example with the loops.  As it stands the description is to general.  The fast `numpy` operations are basic - addition, mutliplication, summation of array values.  It can't compile generic Python functions and do fast whole-array operations on them.

Comment: @Navaro Thank you for your reply. I updated the question and I wrote down a concrete example of the matrix. I hope that will clarify my question.

Comment: @hpaulj g(i,j) is a function that takes scalar inputs i and j. I added a concrete example of M matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify thinking, lets ravel the `i,j` dimensions to one, `ij` dimension.  Can we evaluate 3 arrays:

```
G = g(ij)   # for all ij values
H = h(ij)
F = f(ij, kk)  # for all ij, and all kk
```

In other words, can `g,h,f` be evaluated at multiple values, to produce whole-arrays?

If the `G` and `H` values were the same for all `ij`, or subsets (preferably slices), then

```
F[:, G:H].sum(axis=1)
```

would be the value for all `ij`.

If the `H-G` difference, the size of each slice, was the same, then we can construct a 2d indexing array, `GH` such that

```
F[:, GH].sum(axis=1)
```

In other words we are summing constant size windows of the `F` rows.

But if the `H-G` differences vary across `ij`, I think we are stuck with doing the sum for each `ij` element separately - with Python level loops, or ones complied with `numba` or `cython`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I myself found an answer to this. I first create 3D array F_{i,j,k} = f(i,j,k). And then create a mask_array whose component is Ture if g(i,j) < k < f(i,j), False otherwise. Then I compute the element-wise multiplication of these two arrays, F*mask_array, and then taking the sum over k axis.
For example, this matrix can be efficiently created by the following code.

M_{i,j} = \sum_{k=min(i,j)}^{i+j}\sin{\left( (i+j)^k \right)}

```
#in this example, g(i,j) = min(i,j) and h(i,j) = i+j f(i,j,k) = sin((i+j)^k)
# 0<= i, j <= 2

#kk should range from min g(i,j) to max h(i,j)
ii, jj, kk = np.mgrid[0:3,0:3,0:5]

# k > g(i,j)
frm1 = kk >= jj
frm2 = kk >= ii
frm = np.logical_or(frm1,frm2)

# k < h(i,j)
to = kk <= ii+jj

#mask
k_mask = np.logical_and(frm,to)

def f(i,j,k):
    return np.sin((i+j)**k)

M_before_mask = f(ii,jj,kk)

#Matrix created
M_matrix = (M_before_mask*k_mask).sum(axis=2)
```